# Make a program that allows you to load two lists of 15 numbers each. Inform with a message which of the two lists has a greater cumulative value

Tags: arrays, loops, pseudocode

The 3 optional messages are:
"List 1 major"
"List 2 major"
"Lists are equal"

The program needs to be in pseudocode and declare variables.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: What are you stuck on?  We have no idea what your pseudocode is supposed to look like.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should try to code this for yourself (otherwise how should you learn if you just copy-paste the solution). Then you can show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and explain where the problem is and ask for some help.